# How to custom format a FileTime

Tags: java, date-formatting, java-time

Given a `FileTime fileTime`, how can it be formatted in a custom way to a string?

`String s = fileTime.toString()` provides it in ISO format only.

```
String s = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                              .format(fileTime.toInstant());
```

throws `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: Year`

Comment: did you mean `yyyy` instead of `uuuu`

Comment: @Kal I tried both. `yyyy` just throws `Unsupported field: Year of Era` instead of `Unsupported field: Year`.

Comment: Did you try `toMillis` instead of `toInstant`? Formatting an `Instant` requires timezone.

Comment: @Kal I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366031/obtain-last-modification-date-time-of-file-as-local-date-time-string). How would one proceed with the result of `toMillis`?

Comment: ah yes. I think your best bet is to just attach timezone to the DateTimeFormatter -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229124/format-instant-to-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot format an Instant using a `DateTimeFormatter` instance querying the year.

An `Instant` is representing a single point on the time line. That's why it is not possible to give a correct/unique answer to the question "what's the year/day/time?". It depends on where on the world the question is asked: In New York it differs from Sidney.
But your DateTimeFormatter is asking exactly this question. And that is why you get an `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException`.

You have to convert the `Instance` to a `LocalDateTime` at least:

```
System.out.println(timestampFormatter.format(
    LocalDateTime.ofInstant(fileTime.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()));
```

Answer (score 6):

Personally I find the error message "Unsupported field: Year" misleading. **The real cause is missing timezone.** This information is needed to help the formatter to internally convert the given instant to a human-time-representation. **Solution: Supply the timezone.** Then formatting or parsing an `Instant` is supported - in contrast to the answer of @flo.

**Printing:**

```
String s = 
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .format(Instant.now());
System.out.println(s); // 2015-Oct-30 15:22:32
```

**Parsing:**

The reverse procedure - parsing - does unfortunately not work the same direct way because the format engine of `java.time` is designed such that the formatter only returns a raw `TemporalAccessor` which needs to be converted to the real required type. Example:

```
Instant instant =
  Instant.from(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .parse("2015-Oct-30 15:22:32"));
System.out.println("=>" + instant); // 2015-10-30T14:22:32Z
```

If the input to be parsed contains a timezone offset or an identifier then you can modify the pattern (symbols x, X, z, Z, VV etc.) and leave out the call to `withZone(...)`, and in case of offsets - you really should leave out that call because otherwise the formatter will not use the timezone offset of your input but the supplied one zone (a pitfall I observed in my own tests).

Answer (score 2):

Formatting an `Instant` requires a time-zone. This can be achieved using `withZone(ZoneId)`:

```
String s = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                 .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                 .format(fileTime.toInstant());
```

Answer (score 1):

If your time looks like this

```
2015-01-01T10:10:09
```

Use

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: This is not what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

ZonedDateTime can parse the default string that you get from a FileTime.toString():
(supply your own 'path' in the code snippet below)

```
FileTime fileTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(path);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(fileTime.toString());
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy   HH:mm:ss");   
System.out.println(dtf.format(zonedDateTime));
```

Result:  Saturday, April 18, 2020   13:43:29